# Rigging Sphere with Hair to a cylinder with bones

Tags: rigging

I'm having no luck parenting the below picture.

[image]

I have a sphere on top with hair (in orange) I have a arm with bones/armature. I'm able to parent the bones but I'm unable to connect the sphere with hair. Basically I want the sphere with hair to be locked to the arm and have the arm use the bones.

Any assistance would be appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured it out..

You need to follow the instructions on this video starting at 20 seconds in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5f18T7Rjmc

Basically you need to in object mode select the sphere with hair, then select the armature. Go to Post mode and select the bone you want the sphere hair to connect to. cntrl-p select bone.

done.